# How to create a Host extension method returning a IServiceBusHost in Masstransit 7.1.4

Tags: .net, masstransit

That's my current ConfigureBus method

```
    static IBusControl ConfigureBus()
    {
        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host(new Uri("url"), hostCfg =>
            {
                hostCfg.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "accessKey=");
                hostCfg.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queueName", e =>
            {
                e.Consumer<consumerClass>();
            });
        });
    }
```

Now I need to save the created host in a class property and I have the idea to create an Host extension method returning a IServiceBusHost like this

```
    IServiceBusHost Host = null;
    static IBusControl ConfigureBus()
    {
        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            Host = cfg.Host(new Uri("url"), hostCfg =>
            {
                hostCfg.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "accessKey=");
                hostCfg.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queueName", e =>
            {
                e.Consumer<consumerClass>();
            });
        });
    }
```

But I can't implement this extension method, could someone help me?

```
    public static IServiceBusHost Host(this IServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator configurator, Uri hostAddress, Action<IServiceBusHostConfigurator> configure)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the *Host* was [removed in v7](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/upgrade-v6.html#version-7).

Maybe if you update your question to indicate what you are trying to do with the host, that would help get you the real answer you need.

For instance, if you're trying to connect a receive endpoint, the new [`IReceiveEndpointConnector`](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.0.html#receive-endpoint-connector) interface should be used instead.